# RPC vs REST vs WCF?

Tags: wcf, rest, rpc

Hello I'm currently working on a web application and I would like some of your help in using the correct way to implement my API.

RPC is the way I've started implementing it because that was the most logical thing to do as a new web developer but I've been eyeing RESTful and WCF because they have been mentioned so many times in my research.

Is it common to have a RPC interface for more complex business logic intensive data manipulation and a REST like interface for the "rest".

Comment: Maybe AngularJS with ASP.NET Web API ?

Comment: I am sorry I did change the question my initial question was stupid because I was confused but when it became more clear to me instead of making another question I just changed this one.

Comment: @Julien then your comment makes perfect sense :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> RPC is the way I've started implementing it because that was the most
>   logical thing to do as a new web developer but I've been eyeing
>   RESTful and WCF because they have been mentioned so many times in my
>   research.

Let's de-tangle a bit:

- RPC is a style of web service composition.
- REST is a style of web service composition
- WCF is a technology stack which supports both RPC and REST styles

> Is it common to have a RPC interface for more complex business logic
>   intensive data manipulation and a REST like interface for the "rest".

At best, you could argue it's common to take complex and long running processes *offline*. Whether you do this using RPC or REST makes no difference. However, web services are generally a synchronous technology - although one way calls are supported this kind of semantic is better served by true asynchronous transport like message queues (which are also supported by WCF).